# Setting up unit with Xcode tests for an Objective-C++ code base

Tags: xcode, compiler-errors, linker-errors, objective-c++

My issue is simply that I am getting errors when trying to run a test bundle with Objective-C++.

This is the specific error that I am seeing:

```
/iOS4.2/Tools/RunPlatformUnitTests.include: line 415: 38013 Trace/BPT trap          "${THIN_TEST_RIG}" "${OTHER_TEST_FLAGS}" "${TEST_BUNDLE_PATH}"
/iOS4.2/Tools/RunPlatformUnitTests.include:451: error: Test rig '/iOS4.2/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk/Developer/usr/bin/otest' exited abnormally with code 133 (it may have crashed).
```

I have set some Linker flags including the following on my test bundle:

```
-lxml2
-all_load
```

I know the information is a bit sparse here, my target configuration is gigantic and would probably confuse more than help here, but is there something immediately obvious that I ought to check/confirm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The -all_load flag in the unit tests was the culprit. I don't think unit test bundles agree with it.